# How to Detect the Variable used to initialize a class

Tags: php

I have this simple autoloading script, the only problem is that I do not know what variable my `class1` is initialized. I var_dump the variable $class and it says

`object(class1)[1]`

But when I tried to `$class->someMethod()` variable class is undefined?

on my ClassLib Directory I have a

`-class1.php` and
   `-class2.php`

My COde:

```
function init_load($class){ 
include 'ClassLib/'.$class.'.php'; 
}

function verify_fclass($class){
if(!file_exists('ClassLib/'.$class.'.php')){
    return FALSE;
}else{
    if(!class_exists($class)){
        return FALSE;
    }else{
        return TRUE;
    }
}

}

function init_classes($classes = array()){
foreach($classes as $class){
    if(verify_fclass($class) === FALSE){
        $test[$class.'NotExisting'] = $class;
    }else{
             $test = null;
             $class = new $class;
    }
}
var_dump($class); // what is on class
var_dump($test);  // what is on test
}

$class_array = array('NonExistingClass','class1');
spl_autoload_register('init_load');
init_classes($class_array);

$class->what();
```

Comment: If you have an auto-loader why you check class existence again? show your `init_load`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still have to define the class instance $class outside of the function scope.

That means you should return $class in your init_classes function. The only problem I see here is that you want to be able to instantiate several classes at once so you might have to return an array of classes.

You could try something like this:

```
function init_classes($classes = array()){
    $error = array();
    $instances = array();

    foreach($classes as $class){
        if(verify_fclass($class) === FALSE){
            $error[$class.'NotExisting'] = $class;
        }
        else{
            $test = null;
            $instances[$class] = new $class;
        }
    }
    return array( 'error' => $error, 'instances' => $instances);
}

$class_array = array('NonExistingClass','class1');
$class = $init['instances']['class1'];
$class->what();
```

But then again you could just instantiate the class directly without using an array and the init_classes method...

Comment: Hmmm Not Bad, thankyou i used this instead 
$class = init_classes($class_array)['instances']['class1'];
But i'll figure it out how to get out from this spaghetti code :D

Comment: Of course you can do that too - There's just one caveat. As soon as you want to instantiate more than one class you'll call the function and as such instantiate the objects every time you want to access the class.